# how to change value on mysql with php and view it dynamically without redirection refresh page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

```
<?php echo"<td align ='center'>\".$bookstatus.\"<a href=\"?s_bookstatus&id_commission=$id_commission\"><img src=\"img/refresh.png\" class=\"icon\"/></a></td>"; ?>
```

this link reach to s_bookstatus then change the value of bookstatus.

```
else if(isset($_GET['s_bookstatus']))
{
    $id_commission = $_GET['id_commission'];
    $qrycheck = "select * from commission where id_commission='$id_commission'";
    $rscheck = mysqli_query($con,$qrycheck) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    $rowcheck = mysqli_fetch_array($rscheck);
    $s_bookstatus = $rowcheck['book_status'];
    $id_book = $rowcheck['id_book'];

    $qrybooklist = "select * from booklist where id_book='$id_book' ";
    $rsbooklist = mysqli_query($con,$qrybooklist) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    $rowbooklist = mysqli_fetch_array($rsbooklist);
    $stock = $rowbooklist['stock'];

    if($s_bookstatus == 'Available')
    {
        $check = 'Not Available';
        $newstock = $stock - 1;

    }
    else if($s_bookstatus == 'Not Available')
    {
        $check = 'Available';
        $newstock = $stock + 1;

    }

    mysqli_query($con,"update booklist set stock = $newstock where id_book = '$id_book' ");
    $qry = "update commission set book_status ='$check' where id_commission ='$id_commission' ";
    mysqli_query($con,$qry) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=home.php?commission'>";

}
```

How to change this code to ajax without meta http-equiv refresh so the data changed dynamically in one page.
thank you..

Comment: This won't solve your problem but I recommend you to use PDO instead of _mysqli_ functions AND you definitely should **escape variables before passing it into database**.

Comment: thank you, I will use PDO later, I just learnt PDO yesterday.

Comment: You need to use AJAX. [There is a tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp) that uses jQuery.

Comment: Have you tried anything with AJAX so far? Share some code if you have so we can help you with it. :)

Comment: @MartinHeralecký i already read [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp) i will try it.

Comment: Ok. If you have any problems, feel free to ask a question here.

Comment: I found a method with php store the query and the query send through method $_GET through the sql and back to home.php?commission&query=$query.. @MartinHeralecký

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(isset($_GET['query'])){
            $query = $_GET['query'];
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
        }
        else
        {
        $query = "select * from commission c left join booklist b on c.id_book = b.id_book $filterqry $search";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error($con)); 
        }

<td align ='center'>".$bookstatus."<a href=\"?s_bookstatus&id_commission=$id_commission&query=$query\"><img src=\"img/refresh.png\" class=\"icon\"/></a></td>

else if(isset($_GET['s_bookstatus']))
{
    $id_commission = $_GET['id_commission'];
    $query = $_GET['query'];

    $qrycheck = "select * from commission where id_commission='$id_commission'";
    $rscheck = mysqli_query($con,$qrycheck) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    $rowcheck = mysqli_fetch_array($rscheck);
    $s_bookstatus = $rowcheck['book_status'];
    $id_book = $rowcheck['id_book'];

    $qrybooklist = "select * from booklist where id_book='$id_book' ";
    $rsbooklist = mysqli_query($con,$qrybooklist) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    $rowbooklist = mysqli_fetch_array($rsbooklist);
    $stock = $rowbooklist['stock'];

    if($s_bookstatus == 'Available')
    {
        $check = 'Not Available';
        $newstock = $stock - 1;

    }
    else if($s_bookstatus == 'Not Available')
    {
        $check = 'Available';
        $newstock = $stock + 1;

    }

    mysqli_query($con,"update booklist set stock = $newstock where id_book = '$id_book' ");
    $qry = "update commission set book_status ='$check' where id_commission ='$id_commission' ";
    mysqli_query($con,$qry) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; url=home.php?commission&query=$query \">";

}
```